# How can I distinguish between direct instantiation and instantiation through an association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have an `after_initialize` callback that I would like to happen whenever the model is created or instantiated *directly*, as opposed to loaded through an association in some other place.  Something like this:

```
after_initialize :check_status, if: "instantiated_directly?"
```

such that `MyModel.find(1)` will trigger the check, but `other_model.my_model` will not.

The status is a state variable for a long process, which only needs to be verified before some long-running process starts.  I want to prevent the user from loading the model if the process seems to be in progress.  I'd like to still be able to acces attributes in that model for various other reasons elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing the read is probably not the best vector for ameliorating this issue, nor is a model that tries to reach out of its own scope to determine how to load a wise idea. I would instead recommend you simply add a validation to ensure the record can be modified without interfering with your background processes, a la…

```
validate :safe_to_edit?

def safe_to_edit?
  some_state_variable
end
```

Your model also exposes a `safe_to_edit?` method here that allows your controller or another object to determine the best behavior independently of checking validations, such as if you had a client-side service polling to flag the user when it was safe to edit, or you wanted to delay response and try again in a few seconds in a background job, etc.

Comment: A validation will only work at save, though.  I'm worried about subsequent loads of the model.  The process updates various fields in the model asynchronously.  If this process is interrupted somehow, I do not want the scheduled process to begin again the next day.

Comment: And in any case, I am curious about the answer to my original question, independent of the specifics of this situation.

Comment: You could extend ActiveRecord to do what you want, but I promise you this will bite you in the ass. Just do it right, which is easier, instead of insisting on subverting the tools you're using.

Comment: No, just a safety feature I thought might be helpful.  I really think it is possible to discuss the technical points here without the usual dose of SO moralizing and sweeping judgements about my level of knowledge.  Thanks for your help, though.  Still wondering if it's possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30706/discussion-between-jordanpg-and-coreyward)